# Concurrent interrupts in ARM

Tags: concurrency, arm, interrupt, interrupt-handling, cortex-m

I am new to ARM processors. Atmel ATSAMD20e implements ARM cortex M0+ processor based on ARMv6 architecture. It allows upto 32 external interrupts, with the interrupt signals connected to the nested vector interrupt table (NVIC). Would it be possible to have concurrent interrupts using NVIC? if so,how can we determine the maximum number of interrupts that can be run concurrently? Could someone please point to any documentation that explains handling of concurrent interrupts. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The maximum interrupts that can run "concurrently" are limited by stack space, the number of priority levels, and the number of interrupt sources you have in the system.  You say you have 32 interrupts, the M0+ has 192 levels, and I have no idea how much stack you're willing to sacrifice to get this behavior.  (And "concurrent" is really a misnomer.  they're preempting each other, not running concurrently)

In practice, however, it really doesn't buy much to support more than a few priority levels, if even that.   You only need this if you have an interrupt whose deadline requirements are shorter than your longest interrupt running period.

See here (http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0337e/Cihcbadd.html) for description of what happens on the stack as interrupts get preempted by other interrupts.

Comment: Thank you very much for the precise answer and clarification.

Comment: Just wanted to add a note even though this is old. The M0+ NVIC may support up to 192 priority levels. In reality, most vendors will only implement a few priority bits (as this is a configurable option in how the vendor implements) and so there may be 4, 8, 16, etc. For example, the NXP Kinetis L line only implements 2 bits meaning 4 user priorities.